# How do I convert a Float to an Int in Elm?

Tags: floating-point, integer, elm

If I have a Float value and I want a Int to use elsewhere how do I make that conversion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elm makes it very easy to convert between values!

(Note: Because Elm is functional and all variables are immutable, the value is not actually converted, rather a new equivalent value is created.)

All you have to do is choose what you want to do with the decimals!

Round do the nearest integer with [round](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Basics#round)

```
1.5 |> round -- 2 : Int
```

Round up with [ceiling](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Basics#ceiling)

```
1.5 |> ceiling -- 2 : Int
```

Round down with [floor](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Basics#floor)

```
1.5 |> floor -- 1 : Int
```

Ignore the deimals with [truncate](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Basics#truncate)

```
1.5 |> truncate -- 1 : Int
```

Converting back is just as easy using [toFloat](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Basics#toFloat)

```
1 |> toFloat -- 1.0 : Float
```

Comment: If you know you want to convert a `Float` to an `Int`, you can search for that type signature on Elm Search, e.g. https://klaftertief.github.io/elm-search/?q=Float%20-%3E%20Int